# What's the difference between coindexing and coreferential?

Tags: syntax, grammar, theoretical-linguistics, binding-theory

Here is a sentence. I(i) enjoy yourself(i). Can we say "I" and "yourself" are coindexed but not coreferential?

Comment: There is no difference.  Your example sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conventionally, coreferentiality is indicated with coindexing, i.e. coindexing is the notation for the theoretical concept. Since "I" and "yourself" are not corefential, this is an abuse of the notation; but yeah if you are trying to make a point about notation versus substantive facts about sentences, the words are coindexed, but not coreferential.